# get typescript to emit es6-import statements as-is (for babel & webpack processing afterwards)

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to get typescript to preserve import-statements for later tree-shaking process. 
Here's the problematic import code:

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
```

which emits:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const lodash_1 = require("lodash");
console.log(lodash_1.map);
```

which means my lodash-webpack plugin cannot do its work.
Is there any way to make tsc preserve import-statements?

thank you!

Comment: See the `module` option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to, in your [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), change the **module code generation** option to `ES6` (your seems to currently be `commonjs`).

Either change your `compilerOptions`//`module` to `ES6` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES6",
        ...
}
```

Or, if you are using command line arguments:

```
tsc <otherargs> --module ES6
```

Comment: I just tried that out, and it results in a lot of 'cannot find module' errors. (e.g. node_modules/@types/jsdom/index.d.ts(10,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'parse5'.)

Comment: Try removing the `node_modules` and `npm install` again.

Comment: just removed node_modules & did yarn cache clean & yarn install. still no luck :(

Comment: try adding those modules they are complaining about. such as `yarn add parse5 @types/parse5`

Comment: I also did ```yarn add parse5 @types/parse5``` and verified that ```node_modules/parse5``` and ```node_modules/@types/parse5``` did exist... but still...

Comment: does TSC read 'import'/'require' statements differently when ```module: 'es6'``` ?

Comment: There could be issues. What version of typescript are you using exactly? Try adding `compilerOptions`//`"moduleResolution": "node"` to your `tsconfig.json`. (Or add `--moduleResolution node` if you are using command line.)